# Scripts not injected in Firefox 43.0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-addon

We created an extension for Firefox (we also have a Chrome version), which injects scripts into the page. Here is the code that injects the script in Firefox:

```
for (var i in tabs) {
    if (tabs[i].url.match(possible_urls) !== null) {
        tabs[i].attach({
            contentScriptFile: possible_urls_script_url
        });
    }
}
```

It worked until Firefox 42.0, but since version 43.0 it stopped working. I found [this document](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/11/19/compatibility-for-firefox-43/) and I think the first general item is related to us. But how do we make the script work?

In addition, we would like to check future versions of Chrome and Firefox with our extensions before they are released to the general public. How do we download and use them on Windows and Ubuntu?

`possible_urls_script_url` = "resource://example-at-example-dot-com/data/../lib/content/src/common/first_time_script.js"

I also tried with "resource://example-at-example-dot-com/lib/content/src/common/first_time_script.js" and it doesn't work either.

I found out that with Firefox Developer Edition (45.0a2) it works but with Firefox 43.0 it doesn't.

Also when injecting with `contentScript` (instead of `contentScriptFile`) it still doesn't work on Firefox 43.0. But it works on Firefox Developer Edition (45.0a2).

Comment: Is your extension signed?

Comment: @MaratTanalin Yes, it's signed and enabled.

Comment: Did you try with a new clean profile and/or with Fx 44 Aurora with e10s guaranteedly disabled? I had an issue with Fx 43 Beta that e10s has been enabled after Fx 42beta→43beta upgrade, and there was no way to disable e10s other than use Fx 44 Aurora that has a GUI for enabling/disabling e10s. Enabling e10s breaks many extensions that deal with content of webpages.

Comment: have you checked with the debugger (does the loop execute)? what values can `possible_urls_script_url` contain? have you checked the browser console?

Comment: @the8472 `possible_urls` is a regular expression matching the URL, and `possible_urls_script_url` is the URL of the script to be injected. Both didn't change for at least 6 months. We didn't check with the debugger.

Comment: @MaratTanalin We tried with a new clean profile.

Comment: "possible_urls_script_url is the URL of the script to be injected" doesn't tell me anything new. I asked for values, not a description what it does.

Comment: @the8472 I tried to add console.log but I can't run this extension in debug mode because it's unsigned and Mozilla disabled it. Is it possible to sign it without releasing a new version?

Comment: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing